# How to combine package acronym and hyphenation?

Tags: hyphenation, acronyms

It seems that words part of an acronym defined using the Acronym package have trouble being hyphenated. How can I make sure that the long version of the acronym will be hyphenated correctly?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{acronym}

\hyphenation{Acro-nym}
\acrodef{OA}{Overlengthy Acronym}

\begin{document}
This very very very very lengthy useless sentence contains many words including an \ac{OA} and it should be split.

This very very very very lengthy useless sentence contains many words including an Overlengthy Acronym (OA) and it should be split.
\end{document}
```

On my computer, the preceding MWE results in "Acronym" being split in the second sentence but not in the first one although the produced text is identical.

Comment: I get exactly the same text in both paragraphs, with `Acronym` split across lines.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I added a more recent version of acronym.sty to the folder and it's now corrected (I was using the default ubuntu texlive version). Should I delete the question?

Comment: @Halladba, it cant hurt to leave the question so that someone could find it if they are having the same issue..

Comment: @egreg You could answer this question with "Upgrade your TeXLive installation" so that this question can be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with an outdated version of `acronym` that should be solved by updating it.